# Что такое поиск в вызываюшей строке первого и последнего вхождения в C#?

Tags: c#

```
int Indexof(string value, StringComparison comparison type)
```

Первое и последнее вхождение, можете этого объяснить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим, у нас есть текст:

```
вот мы видим маму; а у мамы мыло; мама моет раму; чтобы чисто было
```

Будем искать в нем подстроку "`мам`". Эта подстрока входит в текст 3 раза:

```
вот мы видим маму; а у мамы мыло; мама моет раму; чтобы чисто было
             ^^^       ^^^        ^^^
             111       222        333
```

`111` - это первое вхождение подстроки. `333` - это последнее вхождение

Соответственно, метод `IndexOf` вернет 13, а `LastIndexOf` вернет 34.

Comment: Ну это если на пальцах рассказать =)

Comment: Насколько я понял, у автора вопроса затруднения с пониманием базовых терминов. В такой ситуации обычно только рассказ "на пальцах" и помогает.